# Windows Photo Viewer: Won't Scan Through Shared Folder

Tags: windows, windows-photo-viewer

Win 11

When I open a LOCAL folder in Explorer and double click on a file, I can use arrow keys to push Photo Viewer to go through all the photos in the folder.

When I do the same steps on a network share (net use g: \server\sharename ), Photo Viewer opens the photo I clicked on, but will NOT respond to arrow keys (or any other key I have tried, like pgup/dn) to go through photos.

a) How do I fix this?
b) How do I go through photos on a shared drive?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

**The core issue is what it is**: Windows Photos / Photo Viewer **is a broken application**: If I punch into Start menu: c:\dir-with-photos\ Explorer comes up, I can double click on any photo, and use up-down keys to view through all photos.  BUT if I do exactly the same steps to g:\dir-with-photos\ (a shared drive), I CANNOT view through all the photos with up-down keys

The completely unintuitive workaround is:

- Open Photo Viewer from Start menu
- ADD a folder to Photo Viewer as a FULL UNC PATH. E.g. \my-nas\sharename\dir-with-photos
- Now I can go through photos this way

The broken behavior from Explorer doesn't change. It is just broken. But this at least gives me a way to get through the content.